# Drawing graph with HighRoller / High Charts php

Tags: php, sql, highcharts

I am using the php wrapper "highroller" to try and graph some data I have in a table in my database.

Now, this code works (from the example):

```
<?php
require_once('../HighRoller/HighRoller.php');
require_once('../HighRoller/HighRollerSeriesData.php');
require_once('../HighRoller/HighRollerLineChart.php');
$chartData = array(5324, 7534, 6234, 7234, 8251, 10324);
$series1 = new HighRollerSeriesData();
$series1->addName('myData')->addData($chartData);
$linechart = new HighRollerLineChart();
$linechart->chart->renderTo = 'linechart';
$linechart->title->text = 'Hello HighRoller';
$linechart->yAxis->title->text = 'Total';
$linechart->addSeries($series1);
?>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HighRoller: set the location of Highcharts library -->
<?php echo HighRoller::setHighChartsLocation("../highcharts/highcharts.js");?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="linechart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo $linechart->renderChart();?>
</script>
</body>
```

However, I am trying to edit the $chartdata = array(5324,...) so that I can pull this from a database. Here is my attempt:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(#,#,#) or die("Couldn't connect to the server.");
$database = mysql_select_db(#, $connection) or die ("Couldn't select the correct database.");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM highroller");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $priceData[] = $row['price'];
}

$chartData = $priceData;

$linechart = new HighRollerLineChart();
$linechart->chart->renderTo = 'linechart';
$linechart->title->text = 'Line Chart';

$series1 = new HighRollerSeriesData();
$series1->addName('myData')->addData($chartData);

$linechart->addSeries($series1);
```

Now, I am not sure why this does not work as the $priceData is an array just like the previous static array.

Also, for reference, here is the function for 'addData' from the library:

```
/** add data to plot in your chart
   * @param $chartdata - array, data provided in 1 of 3 HighCharts supported array formats (array, assoc array or mult-dimensional array)
   * @return void
   */
  public function addData($chartdata){
    if(!is_array($chartdata)){
      die("HighRoller::addData() - data format must be an array.");
    }
    $this->series = array($chartdata);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the question is still valid, but you should make sure that `$chartdata` is an array of numbers, not strings (as it might come from the DB).